# Как правильно передать ссылки с adapter во fragment

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin

Добрый день, у меня иметься adapter для `RecyclerView` такого типа

```
class ListNewsAdapter(val listNewsArrayList: ArrayList<ListNews>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        var title: TextView

        init {
            title = v.findViewById(R.id.titles)
        }
    }

    //Класс который во время загрузки отображает програсс бар
    class ShowProgressBar(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

        lateinit var  mProgressBar: ProgressBar

        init {
            //Бывает что mProgressBar не успевает проинициализироваться
            try {
                mProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
            } catch (e : ExceptionInInitializerError){
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString())
            }

        }

        fun progressBarHide() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Если нечего получить, мы скрываем прогресс бар...")
            mProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }

    }
}
```

После запуска адаптера, мне нужно передать ссылки на класс ShowProgressBar и ViewHolder во Fragment. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мое решение.
1. Передавать ссылки во фрагмент я буду через callback, создав в адаптере интерфейс.

```
interface CustomAdapterCallback{
        fun uploadDataIsArrayList(query : String)
        fun setLinksAdapter(setViewLinkProgressBar : ListNewsAdapter.ShowProgressBar,
                            setViewLinkHolder : ListNewsAdapter.ViewHolder)
    }
```

2. Я выяснил, что view можно получить в методе `onCreateViewHolder`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            val viewClassProgressBar = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.progress_bar_rv, viewGroup, false)

            val viewClassViewHolder = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_list_news, viewGroup, false)

           setListNewsAdapter.setLinksAdapter(ShowProgressBar(viewClassProgressBar), ViewHolder(viewClassViewHolder))


            return when(viewType){
                0 ->{
                    ListNewsAdapter.ViewHolder(viewClassViewHolder)
                }
                else ->{
                    ListNewsAdapter.ShowProgressBar(viewClassProgressBar)
                }
            }
        }
```

Собственно всё, необходимые ссылки я получил при запуски адаптера во Fragment.
**Если вы считаете это решение верным** или оно вам помогло, проголосуйте за него, или оставьте свое решение.

Comment: Второе решение правильное